# CSS Class issue

Tags: html, css

I am currently having trouble with wrapping my head around the idea of class and id selectors. Posted below is my current markup for my navigation.  What I am trying to achieve in my css stylesheet is the horizontal menu.

Why can I not target `.navigation-menu` to style everything within this class (`.navigation-main`)?

```
<nav class="navigation-main">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class"home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class"submit"><a href="submit.html">Submit a Pic</a></li>
        <li class"advertise"><a href="advertise.html">Advertise</a></li>
        <li class"contact"><a href="contact.hml">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

---

CSS

```
.navigation {
display:inline;
```

}

Comment: it might be because you are applying other style on same element in other class

Comment: You show a class class of `.navigation` but the HTML you posted has no elements that use that class. Also, you mention a class named `.navigation-menu`, however your example also does not use this class.

Comment: Can you please edit your question making it precise and clear?

Answer (score 1):

You are not targeting the elements:

```
.navigation-main li{
   display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the question its because you apply the css on the class `navigation` which is not used you need to include this class to apply the css

try

```
 .navigation-main li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: You need to apply `display:inline` to the li`s not the `nav`

Comment: Why are you still targeting `.navigation`? There aren't any elements with that class.

Comment: @JezenThomas i am not targeting the `.navigation` it might be possible that the op is using the `.navigation` at other place

Comment: Yes you are, it's still in your code. And yes, he might be using an element with the class `.navigation` elsewhere, but that's not a conclusion you can draw from his question without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this:

```
.menu li {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be confused about how CSS selectors work. A class needs the same name as it's definition to actually match.

HTML

```
<div class="my-class"></div>
```

CSS

```
.my-class
{
  ...
}
```

So, to answer your question (as it is currently), why you can not target `.navigation-menu` to style everything within `.navigation-main`. It is because your CSS class `.navigation` does not match any classes in your current HTML

To style your NAV with `class="navigation-main"`:

CSS

```
.navigation-main 
{
  ...
}
```

To style only a UL with `class="menu"` that is inside a NAV with `class="navigation-main"`:

CSS

```
.navigation-main .menu 
{
  ...
}
```

To style **all** the elements within NAV `class="navigation-main"`

CSS

```
.navigation-main *
{
  display:inline;
}
```